# How to display all the store data in report using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on Warehouse Management System Project:

1.Item master

2.Inward Items

3.Opening Stock

4.Adjustment Quantity

All is working fine,I want to generate reports.I am storing stock of each item in each table, updated as we inward(increase stock)/outward(decrease stock)/adjustment/openingstock. I want current stock report fine.

Here is im Trying

//sql code

```
SELECT m.uniquecode
     , m.item_barcode
     , m.item_id
     , m.item_name
     , m.size_id
     , m.colour_id
     , m.style_id
     , m.category
     , m.sub_category
     , SUM(i.passedquantity + m.item_quantity + o.opening_stock + a.adjustment_quantity) item_quantity 
  FROM itemmaster m
  join inwardmaster i 
    ON m.item_barcode =i.item_barcode  
  join openingstock o
    on o.item_barcode = i.item_barcode 
  JOIN adjustment_inventory a
    ON a.item_barcode = o.item_barcode  
 WHERE m.item_barcode = o.item_barcode
```

Comment: code shared  in questions part

Comment: A SUM with no aggregation? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query